# Weird error using Python multiprocessing Process / Queue

Tags: python, parallel-processing, queue, multiprocessing

Sorry for the long question, but I couldn't find a better way to summarize it.

I have a program which uses Python's [`multiprocessing`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) to run some calculations in paralell. The communication between processes is done using two [`Queue`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Queue) objects, a `work_queue` and a `result_queue`.
The main process fills up the `work_queue` with data used for the calculations, and then it starts several subprocesses which will consume this queue and and store the results into `result_queue`.

Everything seems to work fine, but as I play a bit with the amount of sample data (i.e. the amount of data that goes into into the `work_queue`) and the number of subprocesses, I've started to get an error that has been puzzling me for hours.

The following code illustrates the problem:

```
# -- queue_bug.py --

import sys
import time
import random
import datetime
import traceback
# Need this to catch the Queue.Empty exception
import Queue
import multiprocessing
from multiprocessing import Process
from multiprocessing import Queue as MultiprocessingQueue

# -------------------------------------------------------------------
# do_calculation
# -------------------------------------------------------------------
def do_calculation(p_name, work_queue, result_queue):
    def log(msg):
        print '%s [%s] %s' % (datetime.datetime.now(), p_name, msg)
    log('Starting up...')
    while True:
        # Get work from queue
        try:
            work = work_queue.get(timeout = 0.1)
            test_id   = work[0]
            test_data = work[1]
        except Queue.Empty:
            break
        # this is just a dummy loop
        for i in range(100):
            test_result = [x * random.random() for x in test_data]
        result_queue.put((test_id, test_data, test_result))
    log('Finished')

# -------------------------------------------------------------------
# main
# -------------------------------------------------------------------
def main():
    def log(msg):
        print '%s [main   ] %s' % (datetime.datetime.now(), msg)
    try:
        num_tests = int(sys.argv[1])
        num_procs = int(sys.argv[2])
    except Exception:
        print 'usage: <prog> number-of-tests number-of-subprocesses'
        sys.exit()

    log('Initializing queues...')
    work_queue   = MultiprocessingQueue()
    result_queue = MultiprocessingQueue()
    log('Creating subprocesses...')
    process_list = []
    for i in range(num_procs):
        p_name = 'PROC_%02d' % (i+1)
        log('    Initializing %s' % p_name)
        p = Process(
            target = do_calculation,
            args   = (p_name, work_queue, result_queue),
            name   = p_name)
        p.daemon = True
        process_list.append(p)
    log('Populating the work_queue...')
    for test_id in range(num_tests):
        work_queue.put((test_id, [test_id]*20))
    log('Work_queue size is %d' % work_queue.qsize())
    log('Starting the subprocesses...')
    for p in process_list:
        p.start()
    log('Waiting until the work_queue is empty...')
    while True:
        log('    Work_queue size is %d' % work_queue.qsize())
        if work_queue.qsize() > 0:
            time.sleep(0.5)
        else:
            break
    log('Waiting until the result_queue is completely filled...')
    while True:
        log('    Result_queue size is %d' % result_queue.qsize())
        if result_queue.qsize() < num_tests:
            time.sleep(0.5)
        else:
            break
    log('Getting results...')
    result_dict = {}
    while True:
        try:
            queue_data           = result_queue.get_nowait()
            test_id              = queue_data[0]
            test_data            = queue_data[1]
            test_result          = queue_data[2]
            result_dict[test_id] = test_result
        except Queue.Empty:
            log('    All results loaded from result_queue')
            break
    log('Storing test results in result_summary...')
    result_summary = []
    for test_id in range(num_tests):
        try:
            test_result = result_dict[test_id]
            result_summary.append((test_id, test_result))
        except KeyError:
            ex = traceback.format_exc()
            log('ERROR: Exception found: %s' % ex)
            sys.exit()
    log('Success.')
    return result_summary

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Now, as I try to run it:

### Attempt 1: 10.000 calculations, 10 subprocesses - OK

```
$ python queue_bug.py 10000 10
2012-12-04 19:24:25.430667 [main   ] Initializing queues...
2012-12-04 19:24:25.440521 [main   ] Creating subprocesses...
2012-12-04 19:24:25.440550 [main   ]     Initializing PROC_01
2012-12-04 19:24:25.440576 [main   ]     Initializing PROC_02
2012-12-04 19:24:25.440597 [main   ]     Initializing PROC_03
2012-12-04 19:24:25.440617 [main   ]     Initializing PROC_04
2012-12-04 19:24:25.440637 [main   ]     Initializing PROC_05
2012-12-04 19:24:25.440656 [main   ]     Initializing PROC_06
2012-12-04 19:24:25.440679 [main   ]     Initializing PROC_07
2012-12-04 19:24:25.440699 [main   ]     Initializing PROC_08
2012-12-04 19:24:25.440721 [main   ]     Initializing PROC_09
2012-12-04 19:24:25.440741 [main   ]     Initializing PROC_10
2012-12-04 19:24:25.440759 [main   ] Populating the work_queue...
2012-12-04 19:24:25.494263 [main   ] Work_queue size is 10000
2012-12-04 19:24:25.494301 [main   ] Starting the subprocesses...
2012-12-04 19:24:25.495515 [PROC_01] Starting up...
2012-12-04 19:24:25.495802 [PROC_02] Starting up...
2012-12-04 19:24:25.496212 [PROC_03] Starting up...
2012-12-04 19:24:25.496557 [PROC_04] Starting up...
2012-12-04 19:24:25.496896 [PROC_05] Starting up...
2012-12-04 19:24:25.497300 [PROC_06] Starting up...
2012-12-04 19:24:25.497705 [PROC_07] Starting up...
2012-12-04 19:24:25.498074 [PROC_08] Starting up...
2012-12-04 19:24:25.498258 [main   ] Waiting until the work_queue is empty...
2012-12-04 19:24:25.498349 [main   ]     Work_queue size is 9974
2012-12-04 19:24:25.498661 [PROC_09] Starting up...
2012-12-04 19:24:25.499765 [PROC_10] Starting up...
2012-12-04 19:24:25.998914 [main   ]     Work_queue size is 0
2012-12-04 19:24:25.998954 [main   ] Waiting until the result_queue is completely filled...
2012-12-04 19:24:25.998976 [main   ]     Result_queue size is 10000
2012-12-04 19:24:25.998993 [main   ] Getting results...
2012-12-04 19:24:26.029774 [PROC_06] Finished
2012-12-04 19:24:26.029798 [PROC_03] Finished
2012-12-04 19:24:26.029824 [PROC_08] Finished
2012-12-04 19:24:26.029853 [PROC_02] Finished
2012-12-04 19:24:26.029868 [PROC_01] Finished
2012-12-04 19:24:26.029898 [PROC_07] Finished
2012-12-04 19:24:26.029921 [PROC_09] Finished
2012-12-04 19:24:26.029942 [PROC_10] Finished
2012-12-04 19:24:26.031040 [PROC_04] Finished
2012-12-04 19:24:26.031057 [PROC_05] Finished
2012-12-04 19:24:26.087804 [main   ]     All results loaded from result_queue
2012-12-04 19:24:26.087844 [main   ] Storing test results in result_summary...
2012-12-04 19:24:26.092477 [main   ] Success.
```

### Attempt 2: 70.000 calculations, 10 subprocesses - ERROR

```
$ python queue_bug.py 70000 10
2012-12-04 19:25:01.083092 [main   ] Initializing queues...
2012-12-04 19:25:01.093483 [main   ] Creating subprocesses...
2012-12-04 19:25:01.093520 [main   ]     Initializing PROC_01
2012-12-04 19:25:01.093548 [main   ]     Initializing PROC_02
2012-12-04 19:25:01.093570 [main   ]     Initializing PROC_03
2012-12-04 19:25:01.093591 [main   ]     Initializing PROC_04
2012-12-04 19:25:01.093612 [main   ]     Initializing PROC_05
2012-12-04 19:25:01.093632 [main   ]     Initializing PROC_06
2012-12-04 19:25:01.093656 [main   ]     Initializing PROC_07
2012-12-04 19:25:01.093676 [main   ]     Initializing PROC_08
2012-12-04 19:25:01.093699 [main   ]     Initializing PROC_09
2012-12-04 19:25:01.093720 [main   ]     Initializing PROC_10
2012-12-04 19:25:01.093738 [main   ] Populating the work_queue...
2012-12-04 19:25:01.395974 [main   ] Work_queue size is 70000
2012-12-04 19:25:01.396012 [main   ] Starting the subprocesses...
2012-12-04 19:25:01.397601 [PROC_01] Starting up...
2012-12-04 19:25:01.398183 [PROC_02] Starting up...
2012-12-04 19:25:01.398545 [PROC_03] Starting up...
2012-12-04 19:25:01.399021 [PROC_04] Starting up...
2012-12-04 19:25:01.399621 [PROC_05] Starting up...
2012-12-04 19:25:01.400137 [PROC_06] Starting up...
2012-12-04 19:25:01.400675 [PROC_07] Starting up...
2012-12-04 19:25:01.401200 [PROC_08] Starting up...
2012-12-04 19:25:01.401645 [main   ] Waiting until the work_queue is empty...
2012-12-04 19:25:01.401691 [PROC_09] Starting up...
2012-12-04 19:25:01.401738 [main   ]     Work_queue size is 69959
2012-12-04 19:25:01.402387 [PROC_10] Starting up...
2012-12-04 19:25:01.902063 [main   ]     Work_queue size is 58415
2012-12-04 19:25:02.402640 [main   ]     Work_queue size is 47302
2012-12-04 19:25:02.903067 [main   ]     Work_queue size is 36145
2012-12-04 19:25:03.403650 [main   ]     Work_queue size is 24992
2012-12-04 19:25:03.904065 [main   ]     Work_queue size is 13481
2012-12-04 19:25:04.404643 [main   ]     Work_queue size is 1951
2012-12-04 19:25:04.588562 [PROC_02] Finished
2012-12-04 19:25:04.588580 [PROC_06] Finished
2012-12-04 19:25:04.588611 [PROC_10] Finished
2012-12-04 19:25:04.588631 [PROC_03] Finished
2012-12-04 19:25:04.589705 [PROC_04] Finished
2012-12-04 19:25:04.589741 [PROC_09] Finished
2012-12-04 19:25:04.589764 [PROC_05] Finished
2012-12-04 19:25:04.589791 [PROC_08] Finished
2012-12-04 19:25:04.589814 [PROC_01] Finished
2012-12-04 19:25:04.589844 [PROC_07] Finished
2012-12-04 19:25:04.905065 [main   ]     Work_queue size is 0
2012-12-04 19:25:04.905098 [main   ] Waiting until the result_queue is completely filled...
2012-12-04 19:25:04.905121 [main   ]     Result_queue size is 70000
2012-12-04 19:25:04.905140 [main   ] Getting results...
2012-12-04 19:25:05.012083 [main   ]     All results loaded from result_queue
2012-12-04 19:25:05.012140 [main   ] Storing test results in result_summary...
2012-12-04 19:25:05.020498 [main   ] ERROR: Exception found: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "queue_bug.py", line 95, in main
    test_result = result_dict[test_id]
KeyError: 10647
```

On the second attempt I get a **KeyError** when trying to read the data from `result_dict`.
This dictionary is filled with data got from the `result_queue`, therefore I suspect it must be related to it.

I also noticed that everytime I run it with a combination of arguments that fails (e.g. 70000 / 10), the `KeyError` is raised on a different key, which seems to indicate some concurrency / synchronization issue.

Last but not least, the likelihood to reproduce it increases if the size of the sample data or the number of subprocesses increases.

Any ideas?

Comment: You might be better of using `JoinabelQueue` ( http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.JoinableQueue ) for your work queue.  You can then drop most of the wait loops.

Comment: For that matter, there's `multiprocessing.Pool` with it's `map()`, that would cut out most of the management code here.  Still though, doesn't explain what's going on here...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I added a little extra debugging to your example code, and I think I found the problem.  Aside from the existing comments about using `JoinableQueue`, the main problem is that at the end when you process the results you do something like:

```
try:
    queue_data = result_queue.get_nowait()
except Queue.Empty:
    break
```

But `Queue.Empty` can be raised even if the queue is not actually empty, but just because `get_nowait()` timed out too quickly.  Instead you should try:

```
try:
    queue_data = result_queue.get_nowait()
except Queue.Empty:
    if result_queue.qsize() < 1:
        break
```

In other words, ensure that the queue is really actually empty before breaking out of the loop.

Comment: Although I have used `qsize()`, I didn't want to depend on it because the documentation (http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Queue.qsize) says: *Return the approximate size of the queue. Because of multithreading / multiprocessing semantics, this number is not reliable.* But this is a good solution anyway, thanks +1.

Comment: @Mr.E. `qsize` is unreliable if you have multiple process working on the queue. At this point in your code you know that there is only one process it should be safe.

Answer (score 3):

Your bug is in the loop where you get data out of the result queue

```
 while result_queue.qsize() > 0:
        try:
            queue_data           = result_queue.get()
            test_id              = queue_data[0]
            test_data            = queue_data[1]
            test_result          = queue_data[2]
            result_dict[test_id] = test_result
        except Queue.Empty:
            log('    All results loaded from result_queue')
            break
```

Your `get_nowait` was returning empty when there were still results left.  I suspect that there is some over head behind the scenes that goes up with the number of threads that wasn't finishing before it gave up.

Comment: Wow, I never ever would think that `Queue.Empty` could be raised when there were still results left. Thanks, it works now.